# how to append a select box with selected value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to append a select box with a selected value onclick event.
i am having 3 options like option1, option2, option3 .... after selecting one option and pressing button , the select box need to clone with selected value...? how to do that in jquery
here is my code

```
var dir_lay = $('.dir-insp-new-lay').clone();
var dir_data = $('<form id="dir_frm">').append(dir_lay).serialize();
var write_html = $('<form id="dir_frm">').append(dir_lay);                                       
$('.original').html(write_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `value` of your clone by setting `.val($(yourPreviousSelect).val())` :

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var newSelect = $('select').clone();
  newSelect.val($('select').val());
  $('body').append(newSelect);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Clone !</button>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```